# Access Hbase with Pig

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I'm trying to load data from **HBase (1.1.2)** using **Pig (0.15.0)**.  I've tried registering too many JARs without any success. I'm able to access it with Java but not with Pig. Below I've registered all JARs. the first five, then `lib/*.jar then target/alternateLocation/*.jar` which my Java code was using. Everything is installed on my local PC and HBase is running on HDFS.

```
--REGISTER /home/halmousli/hbase-1.1.2/lib/*.jar

--REGISTER /home/halmousli/mygit/Hbase/apachehbase/target/alternateLocation/*.jar

set hbase.zookeeper.quorum 'localhost'
data = LOAD 'hbase://emp'       USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('professional:designation', '-loadKey true')
   as (id:bytearray,prof:CHARARRAY);
DUMP data;
```

> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[professional:designation, -loadKey true]'
>   Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: 
>    pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[professional:designation, -loadKey true]'
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:199)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1735)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1443)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:387)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:412)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:398)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:171)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:749)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
>       at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:631)
>       at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
>   Caused by: 
>   /home/halmousli/mygit/Pig/mavenpigtester/src/main/resources/hbaseGetter.pig, line 21, column 7> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[professional:designation, -loadKey true]'
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:897)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3568)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1625)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
>       ... 19 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[professional:designation, -loadKey true]'
>       at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:772)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:885)
>       ... 25 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:740)
>       ... 26 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setCacheBlocks(Z)V
>       at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.initScan(HBaseStorage.java:427)
>       at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.(HBaseStorage.java:368)
>       ... 31 more
>   2015-12-30 11:19:14,794 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
>    pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[professional:designation, -loadKey true]'
>   Details at logfile: /home/halmousli/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/pig_1451492353570.log

I do not know why I am seeing caused by: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setCacheBlocks`. In my Java code, I am able to find that function and run it but not in Pig and I am using the same jars.

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setCacheBlocks(true);
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem or to other way to access HBase from Pig?. Thanks.

Comment: Indent your code! Select all of the code snippets and press ctrl+k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error above was incompatibility between my hadoop version and hbase. I installed hbase-0.98.16-hadoop2 and the pig code is running without errors.

Generally when you see java.lang.NoSuchMethodError then it can be an indication of incompatibility between versions.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access hbase using pig more secure version will be hbase 0.98 and pig 0.15. I hope this will resolve your integration problem

Comment: elaborate your answer

Answer (score 0):

HBase community broke the binary compatibility when they changed the return value of `#setCacheBlocks()` from 'void' to 'Scan'. It is expecting to find the `setCacheBlocks()` from HBase 0.98, but finds the version of HBase 1.1.2.

One solution is to recompile Pig to use HBase 1.1.2.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4743